# Get top(N) or single value using Bql

Tags: acumatica

How is it possible to use a PXSelect statement so that it retrieves the Top(N) or the first value for a particular DAC.

Let's say that I have a table with a sequence number and I want to obtain the record with the largest sequence number. How can I do that?

Of course, I would like that for performance reasons, SQL just sends 1 record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SelectWindowed in place of Select on your `PXSelect` to get the top N records. In the example below it will get the Top 1. If you change the `totalRows` value of 1 to 5 it would get the top 5 (except you would have to loop or get the `PXResultSet` to use all 5 records retrieved.)

**Top 1 Example:**

```
DiscountSequence firstRow = PXSelect<DiscountSequence, 
    Where<DiscountSequence.discountID, Equal<Required<DiscountSequence.discountID>>>
        >.SelectWindowed(this, 0, 1, someDiscountID);
```

**Top 5 Example:**

```
foreach (DiscountSequence row in PXSelect<DiscountSequence, 
    Where<DiscountSequence.discountID, Equal<Required<DiscountSequence.discountID>>>
        >.SelectWindowed(this, 0, 5, someDiscountID))
{
    //5 rows returned
}
```

Comment: Does this return the fifth record in case if value is set to 5?

Comment: @Petrosov This function parameters are documented: 
        //   startRow:
        //     The 0-based index of the first data record to retrieve.
        //
        //   totalRows:
        //     The number of data records to retrieve.

Comment: yes it should return a total of 5 rows in the results. Changing the start row value will change the top value used in SQL such as asking for a start row of 1 with total rows of 5 would result in a sql query of top 6 with a return of the 2nd to 6th row in the results.